# How do I tell if a lightbulb is LED?

Tags: light

I have this bulb, that I didn't buy myself, and I don't have the packaging, nor do I know the price or anything. The writing says:

```
SOFT STYLE Lighting LB443 Standard 6W E27 3000K 230W/50Hz CE
```

I feel quite sure it is LED, simply because when I turn it on it is at full capacity right away, unlike the energy saving bulbs in the past that took some time to get up to full capacity.

What do you say, can I trust that this is LED?

[image]

The part with the fins is porcelaine. The glass is glass, not plastic.

Comment: It's quite hard to get a LED bulb to 3000 K, this sounds more like a high-end CFL to me.

Comment: Got a photo of it? 6W CFLs are rare, but not unknown. A look at the internal structure should give a very good idea. If it has heatsink fins it's definitely LED, but they're not necessary at 6W.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany in Europe, low wattage CFL are very common. And a E27 230V bulb is probably bought in Europe. As for the heatsink, I don't know. I haven't seen high wattage LED bulbs, but the small ones just have a very large base, just like the small CFLs. Maybe there is some kind of heatsink hidden there. The designers make them look the same on purpose, so they will be attractive when mounted on a chandelier.

Comment: @rumtscho if I Google for 'led 3000k' I get loads of hits. So I suspect availability shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Ooops, I thought I added a picture. It's there now.

Comment: Is disassembling the bulb an option? That will give you an answer pretty fast.

Answer (score 3):

The fins, together with the long neck and the short "glass" bulb clearly indicate the bulb in the picture is an LED lamp. A CFL would have a large glass container or folded/bent glass tube.

Comment: +1 I think I agree, but it's not a slam-dunk. There are somewhat similarly shaped [CFL lamps](http://www.econef.co.uk/shop/order/megaman-cfl-e27-11watt-warm-white-dimmable/)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - the fins are a heat sink. I've never seen such a heat sink on a CFL. Personally, I see no reason not to think it's an LED.